# Is it possible to use a higher version of TypeScript than 1.0.1 in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I'd like to take advantage of some of the faster compilation and other newer features of TypeScript than what we get with the 1.0.1 version that seems to be the only one that comes with the TypeScript 1.0.1 Tools for Visual Studio 2012 plugin.  Is this possible?

Comment: Not really answering your question but you might want to look at the (free) community edition for VS 2013! Because if I remember it correctly 1.0 was the last one for 2012

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing Xbox One media app development and am forced to stick with VS 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfect, but for what it's worth you can swap out the compiler and language service by following these instructions posted by Daniel Rosenwasser.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1110#issuecomment-62451204

**Abbreviated:**
Backup and replace the `tsc.js` files under here:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\` with one you want to use.

Backup and replace the `typescriptServices.js` under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript` with the one you want to use.

VS 2012 may be able to take TypeScript 1.1 fairly safely because it's largely compatible with 1.0, but 1.3 or 1.4 perhaps not - I haven't tried it.

You can get the download from the GitHub TypeScript releases page and the compiled `.js` files are in the `bin` folder so you don't even have to run Jake if you download a full release.

Answer (score 0):

So I asked this question on the TypeScript github page and got the following answer:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2564

Basically, it looks like 2012 only supports up to version 1.0.1.  However, as a work-around, it may be possible for me to isolate my .ts files in an external Visual Studio 2013 or 2015 project and use that project to generate the .js files used by my Visual Studio 2012 project.  It's a bit of a hack, but it's currently the only solution unless someone wants to create an new TypeScript plugin for VS 2012.